# Simpler Way of Changing Components Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been developing WPF for a while now and there's something that really bothers me. I have to do a method do change some components visibily for some reason and the code always gets huge and dirty.

This is merely an example of how I change a `ComboBox` items visibility according to the result of a `IntegerUpDown`:

```
private void _numClass_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          

        if (_numClass.Value >= 2)
        {
            _segunda.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _terca.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _quarta.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _quinta.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _sexta.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _sabado.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            _segundaQuarta.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _terçaQuinta.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            _segunda.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _terca.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _quarta.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _quinta.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _sexta.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _sabado.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            _segundaQuarta.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _terçaQuinta.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way of changing the visibility of a relatively large amount of components without repeting tiresomely these "Visibily.Whatever"?

**EDIT:** Here's the XAML of the code. But just reminding, *i do want a way to change every component visibility in a simpler way, not just in this case.*

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Margin="526,200,0,0" SelectionChanged="cbxDate_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_segunda" Content="Segunda"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_terca" Content="Terça"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_quarta" Content="Quarta"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_quinta" Content="Quinta"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_sexta" Content="Sexta"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_sabado" Content="Sábado"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_segundaQuarta" Content="Segunda e Quarta" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="_terçaQuinta" Content="Terça e Quinta" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Post your XAML as well.

Comment: @sthotakura there it is.

Comment: Usually you should use data binding and MVVM to make the code easier to maintain by having less coupling between code and UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use any binding? You should really look into it, it's the cornerstone of WPF. In this case, you could simply use two visibility properties (you could do more complex things too, like simply bind to the `_numClass.Value` and create a custom ValueConverter that returned the correct Visibility based on the value, but that's more advanced):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Margin="526,200,0,0" SelectionChanged="cbxDate_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Segunda" Visibility="{Binding Class1Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Terça" Visibility="{Binding Class1Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Quarta" Visibility="{Binding Class1Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Quinta" Visibility="{Binding Class1Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Sexta" Visibility="{Binding Class1Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Sábado" Visibility="{Binding Class1Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Segunda e Quarta" Visibility="{Binding Class2Visiblity}"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Terça e Quinta" Visibility="{Binding Class2Visiblity}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

And in your code, add some properties with INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
private Visibility class1Visibilty = Visibility.Visible;
public Visibility Class1Visiblity
{
    get
    {
        return class1Visibilty;
    }
    set
    {
        class1Visibility = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Class1Visibility");
    }
}

private Visibility class2Visibilty = Visibility.Collapsed;
public Visibility Class2Visiblity
{
    get
    {
        return class2Visibilty;
    }
    set
    {
        class2Visibility = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Class2Visibility");
    }
}

private void _numClass_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          

    if (_numClass.Value >= 2)
    {
        Class1Visiblity = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Class2Visiblity = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        Class1Visiblity = Visibility.Visible;
        Class2Visiblity = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

You will need to set your class containing the properties as the DataContext. This is usually done as part of a ViewModel (with XAML in the associated View).

As I mentioned, data binding is a core concept of WPF and you should really be using it as much as possible - it'll make life a lot easier further down the road. Take a look at some tutorials:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx